(`Cmark-gfm`) error while building the Cmakelists.txt file of Swift Open-Source Project
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:862 (find_package):
[cmake]   Could not find a package configuration file provided by "cmark-gfm" with
[cmake]   any of the following names:
[cmake] 
[cmake]     cmark-gfmConfig.cmake
[cmake]     cmark-gfm-config.cmake
[cmake] 
[cmake]   Add the installation prefix of "cmark-gfm" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
[cmake]   "cmark-gfm_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
[cmake]   "cmark-gfm" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
[cmake]   been installed.

I downloaded the Swift Open-Source file to contribute in it but I am facing problem in the building the CMakeLists.txt file of that and I had already downloaded the "Cmake" and "Cmark-gfm" file through homebrew but again and again it showing the error of "
Cmark-gfm" not install how do I solve this issue

The first question to ask yourself is whether your cmark-gfm installation contains any file called cmark-gfmConfig.cmake or cmark-gfm-config.cmake. If it does then the only problem is that cmake doesn't know where these files are and you just follow the instructions given in the error message. If not then you are going to have to write these files yourself. Consult the cmake documentation.

Getting Swift to compile locally is so challenging,
from my experience, you need to have the following in your CMake options:

note: you need to change the path to your swift-project

cmark-gfm_DIR=/Users/mostafa.essam/swift-project/build/Ninja-RelWithDebInfoAssert/cmark-macosx-arm64/cmake/modules/

-Dcmark-gfm_DIR:PATH=/Users/mostafa.essam/swift-project/build/Ninja-RelWithDebInfoAssert/cmark-macosx-arm64/cmake/modules/

-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/Users/mostafa.essam/swift-project/build/Ninja-RelWithDebInfoAssert/llvm-macosx-arm64/lib/cmake/llvm

-DLLVM_DIR=/Users/mostafa.essam/swift-project/build/Ninja-RelWithDebInfoAssert/llvm-macosx-arm64/lib/cmake/llvm/

-DClang_DIR=/Users/mostafa.essam/swift-project/build/Ninja-RelWithDebInfoAssert/llvm-macosx-arm64/lib/cmake/clang

-DSWIFT_PATH_TO_CMARK_BUILD=/Users/mostafa.essam/swift-project/build/Ninja-RelWithDebInfoAssert/cmark-macosx-arm64

for reference, this's how it looks when configured using CLion:

